# How does self property refer to Instance object when using escaping closure ? (Swift 3)

Tags: swift

Here is example :

```
var completionHandlers: [() -> Void] = []
func someFunctionWithEscapingClosure(completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    completionHandlers.append(completionHandler)
}

SomeClass {
    var x = 10
    func doSomething() {
        someFunctionWithEscapingClosure { self.x = 100 }

    }
}


let instance = SomeClass()
instance.doSomething()
```

When calling instance.doSomething() it appends closure to array completionHandlers.It becomes :

var completionHandlers: = [{ self.x = 100 }
]

When calling `completionHandlers.first?()` , it invokes `{ self.x = 100 }` and then x becomes 100.

```
completionHandlers.first?()
print(instance.x)
// Prints "100"
```

**My Question** is `{ self.x = 100 }` in the array  is

something like this : `{ instance.x = 100 }` ? I mean `self` refer to object instance even we used it outside of instance class ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below in comments, you ask:

> Inside of instance class, `self.x` equals instance property `x`. Outside of instance class when we call closure, is `self.x` still instance property `x`?

Yes. The `self` inside the closure refers to the object that created the closure, not to the object that ends up calling the closure (possibly much later). So if object `A` passes a closure that refers to `self.x` to another object, `B`, when `B` calls that closure, the `self.x` still refer's to `A`'s `x` property, not `B`'s.

---

In answer to the original question, yes, you can refer to whatever instance you want. It doesn't have to be `self`.

The abstract way you phrase the question, though, makes me a bit suspicious. This question of "can I update any other instance" introduces some faint hints of code smell. The advantage of the closure pattern is that you're letting the object initiating some action to supply a closure that dictates what should happen in the first object when this other object finishes some task, keeping everything nicely, loosely coupled.

But when you start updating other unrelated objects, things start to feel a bit more tightly coupled, again. It all comes down to what this `instance` is and what relationship it bears to the `self` that created the closure.

But, in short, yes, you can update properties or call methods on items other than `self`, but we'd need to better understand what those various objects were to comment on whether it's a good idea in this case or not.

Comment: Inside of instance class , self.x equals instance property x. Outside of instance class when we call closure , is self.x still instance property x ?

Comment: Yep. The `self` inside the closure refers to the object that created the closure, not to the object that ends up calling the closure (possibly much later). Therein rests the power of closures.

Comment: Thank you that is what I want to hear .

Comment: Hey, welcome to 200k - sorry I missed the actual moment.